# How to Keep Your Data in Sync Across Platforms

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, iphone

Suppose I have project made on platform *Android,Iphone and Webapp*.I want to keep all application across all platform to be in sync with each other for example like anybody made any change I want the other to get notified about that change even on different platform immediately.

Solution that I so for can think of are the following:

> 1.Using push notification to keep everybody notified about the changes(seems less reliable).
>   2.Using any real time server like **"App warp"** to keep notifying anybody.

Could anybody suggest be the better ways to get figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i prefer push notification.

Comment: thanks for reply @Secondo.i was wondering about a situation like having so many users to notify,so it will take lot time to server to go through loop to notify every user which going to take little time.what do you think about it?